# Can I put CSS , HTML AND JAVASCRIPT in one file using a code editor such as Sublime Text or Atom.io ? Thnx

Tags: javascript, html, css, sublimetext3, atom-editor

If yes how can I do it 
And if Sublime Text or Atom.io can't do it is there any other editor?

Comment: Sublime Text is just a text editor.  You can put anything you want in a text file.

Comment: You can find this out by trying it yourself.

Comment: Why yes, yes you can put text into a file using a text editor. You should try it! It's how virtually all of us create the files we use for this type of work.

Comment: You can create one html file and put style tag for inline css and script tag for JS code. If you want to automatically combine these files into single html file then you can use some builder and then run build. Text editors are not relevant. You should edit your question and ask maybe "How can I combine HTML, JS and CSS file into single HTML file" or something like this

Answer (score 0):

omg what a question...

do it in 1 file like this:

```
<HTML>
  <head>
    <style>
      -- your css styles --
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    -- your html tags --

    <script>
      -- your js scripts
    </script>
  </body>
</HTML>
```